# getting unresolved principal when creating ACL in oracle

Tags: oracle, http, acl

I was trying to create an ACL to use http request with Oracle but I don't why it's not working here :

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl         => 'www.xml',
                                    description => 'WWW ACL',
                                    principal   => 'hr',
                                    is_grant    => true,
                                    privilege   => 'connect');
END;
/
```

This is the error :

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uppercase HR, not lower case hr:

```
principal   => 'HR',
```